# How to convert Ubuntu cursor to Windows and conversely?

Tags: themes, customization, cursor

Is it possible to convert ubuntu cursor theme to windows .cur and .ani. and make ubuntu cursor theme from Windows .cur & .ani files? If so, How

thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  I don't remember the tools I used to use to do it, however.  xcursorgen was one.  I also had a plugin for GIMP that would edit X (ubuntu) cursors, so I could export the images.  And if you Google for something like 'free make Windows cursors' you will get a bajillion results, many/most of which will run in Wine.  So no solution from me, but some suggestions anyway.  :)

Answer (score 1):

[Gursor Maker](http://gursormaker.sourceforge.net/) allows to edit cursors for X and allows to import themes made for Stardock CursorXP

Answer (score 1):

Use [RealWorld Cursur Editor](http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-maker) with Linux Xcursur Codec if you are on Windows.